# How can I link to last week's date in a given row and return the correct date using a hyperlink in google sheets

Tags: date, google-sheets, hyperlink, sql-date-functions

How can I link to last week's date in a given row and return the correct date using a hyperlink in google sheets

not really 100% sure of my formula.

Comment: Doesn't make sense.

Comment: Hi-sorry about that...My data consists of weekly dates in a given row. Then, I want to use a hyperlink in Cell A1 referencing last week's date (jump to last week). i hope this makes sense. Thank you

Comment: Please post few sample data and then show your desired output. You may share a sample google-sheet.

Comment: hi -  this is the file --- 
  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oOZwiWSP0Cwo_UHmqAh27vWvvxsP-dsvNyG1z6Wvuzs/edit#gid=1515315831

Comment: Your sheet is private. Make it public. Edit permission.

Comment: can you kindly try again? thank you so much Sir

Comment: @Izl open your own shared link in an Incogito Window / Private Browsing / etc. to try it. Go back and fix the Share permissions until you can open it in Incognito, without authenticating or requesting permission.

Comment: Additionally, your question should contain enough information so someone unfamiliar with your particular file and goal could simply read your question and be able to answer it. It should show research, how far your solutions got, what broke, etc. Your question, right now as written, is unanswerable. [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).